# Quattro Stagioni pizza comes out unbalanced

Tags: flavor, pizza

I like to make my own pizzas from scratch, including kneading the dough myself etc, and they usually work out pretty fine.
But there is one problem with Quattro Stagioni pizzas, where you're supposed to put different ingredients in different segments of the pizza.
For instance ham, bell peppers, mushrooms and artichokes. If I do that, the parts containing ham and bell pepper turn out great, but the problem is, that half is *much* more flavourful than the parts with artichokes and mushrooms.
(With pizzas where you can spread out all ingredients all over, this is no problem, since all the flavours will blend together very nicely.)

So, how to avoid half of the pizza being very bland in comparison to the savoury other half?
Can I pour extra salt on those parts? The problem is, none of the recipes I consulted mention anything about adding salt.
So, does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Yes, I believe you mean "bell pepper", but [paprika](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paprika) could very well be a part of your perfect pizza (see my answer).

Comment: @Jolenealaska Yes, a bit of Wikipediaing convinced me that the correct term is indeed bell pepper. I edited. Thanks!

Comment: Spread tomato  (salted to taste and mozzarella all over ) than go with artichokes ham mushroom and small  black olives sectors. It should turn out ok. Balance and not exceeding with topping is the secret . Unless you are stuck with americae style (over topping) ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seasoning is definitely a big part of your solution. Look at [this recipe from Wolfgang Puck](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/four-seasons-pizza-pizza-quattro-stagione-recipe.html).

> saute the mushrooms in the olive oil until done. Season with salt and pepper

and

> Sprinkle basil over tomato section and grated Parmesan over the mushroom section

Taste your mushrooms and artichokes with different cheeses, herbs, spices, whatever. Certainly use additional salt if it seems warranted. Most importantly, *taste* your toppings with various complimentary flavors, always keeping in mind that you want the pizza to be a harmonious whole. Experiment!

Comment: If that half of the pizza is really lacking salt and/or umami, herbs and spices alone could make it taste harsh, bitter or medicinal... cheeses will help because they are usually salty and umami.

Comment: @rackandboneman  I stressed tasting and experimentation with different cheeses, herbs, spices, salt, whatever to avoid unpleasantness like bitterness or medicinal flavor.

Answer (score 1):

Ham is salty and bleeds out brine that will also salt the bell peppers so yes, salt balance is upset ... and why should you not add salt to a part of your pizza that evidently needs salt? If you are worried about the salt staying on the pizza as grains, grind it to fine dust (dose carefully, very fine salt is very potent :). Mind that the mushrooms/artichokes might cook a bit quicker - salt will draw water from them and work against the heat-limiting effect of that water. Having some oil on them will help against them drying out TOO much.